# Ember.js with Jquery-ui sortable

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, ember.js

Hey I'm having some issues with Ember.js and jquery-ui sortable.  I realise there are a few solutions around, mostly involving safeClone(), but these strip out the metamorph tags, while I still need an update.

What is happening at the moment is the sortable plugin is moving the content, but not the outer metamorph tags:  I wrote a helper which cloned the metamorph tags along with the content, but it didn't make any difference to the operation.

```
safeClone: function() {
  var clone = this;
  prev = clone.prev();
  clone = prev.add(clone);
  clone = clone.add(clone.next());

  clone = $(clone).clone();
  console.log(clone);
  return clone;
}
```

I've uploaded a jsfiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/reubenposthuma/Bx5GL/7/.  It's not working perfectly, but any pointers would be appreciated!